# Does turtle have an onkeyhold method

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

In a program I am writing, turtle's onkey() method doesn't do exactly what I need. I know there are also onkeypress and onkeyrelease but neither do what I need. Is there a method for continuously running a function while a key is held? Such as

```
import turtle
num = 0
def add():
    global num
    num += 1
    print(num)
turtle.onkey(add, "Up")
turtle.listen()
turtle.mainloop()
```

If you did something like this, for taking the keyboard input, onkey only responds once, and it only responds on the release of the key. Is there a method that would continuously run the function while it is being held down?

Comment: You could implement such using `onkeypress()` and `onkeyrelease()` in combination.  Here's the catch: some operating systems implement key repeat such that you'll get a series of press and release events while the key is being held down.  You won't be able to distinguish the user action from the system repeat.  Unless you turn off key repeat at the OS level.

Answer (score 0):

Below's a rough example that does what you describe using `onkeypress(`) and `onkeyrelease()` in combination.  Once you press 'Up' it will start counting whole seconds until you release that key.  Then it will write to the screen the number of whole seconds the key was held:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT = ('Arial', 36, 'normal')

def add_start():
    global seconds
    print('pressed')
    if seconds < 0:
        turtle.undo()  # remove previous time
        seconds = 0
        screen.ontimer(add, 1000)

def add():
    global seconds

    if seconds >= 0:
        seconds += 1
        screen.ontimer(add, 1000)

def add_stop():
    global seconds
    print('released')
    turtle.write(seconds, align='center', font=FONT)
    seconds = -1

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

turtle.write(0, align='center', font=FONT)

seconds = -1

screen.onkeypress(add_start, 'Up')
screen.onkeyrelease(add_stop, 'Up')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Here's the catch: you need to turn off key repeat at the operating system level on your system.  For example, On my Mac, in System Preferences / Keyboard, I'd do:

[image]

Otherwise the system will generate press and release events as part of standard key repeat.